# Updating matplotlib plot during code execution

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have found that the latest update to python/matplotlib has broken a crucial feature, namely, the ability to regularly update or "refresh" a matplotlib plot during code execution. Below is a minimally (non-)working example.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from time import sleep

x = np.array([0])
y = np.array([0])

figure()
for i in range(51):
    gca().cla()
    plot(x,y)
    xlim([0,50])
    ylim([0,2500])
    draw()
    show(block = False)
    x = np.append(x,[x[-1]+1])
    y = np.append(y,[x[-1]**2])
    sleep(0.01)
```

If I run this program using Python 3.4.3 and matplotlib 1.4.3, I can see the plot continually update, and the curve grows as the program runs. However, using Python 3.5.1 with matplotlib 1.5.3, the matplotlib window opens but does not show the plot. Instead, it continually shows the window is "not responding" and only presents the final plot when the code finishes executing.

What can I do about this? Is there some way to achieve the functionality that I want using the latest release?

Note: I'm running this from the default IDLE environment if that makes a difference.

Comment: have you tried this line between your imports: `% matplotlib inline`?

Comment: @estebanpdl It seems to me that command is meant for use in ipython to force the plot to appear inside the command window. I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting. I'm used to draw interactive plots a little bit differently:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep

x = np.array([0])
y = np.array([0])

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim([0,50])
ax.set_ylim([0,2500])
line,  = ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
for i in range(51):
    x = np.append(x,[x[-1]+1])
    y = np.append(y,[x[-1]**2])
    line.set_data(x,y)
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

Can you (or anyone) check if this shows the same problems in Matplotlib 1.5?

Comment: Yes, that would work for me as well in 1.4. The `show` I have at the end isn't strictly necessary and it's only the `draw` command that is really needed, but I keep it there because it doesn't hurt anything. The only other difference is `ion`, which I've found doesn't really do anything to help.

Comment: The question is, if it is working in Matplotlib 1.5 ?!

Comment: @FelixXu That would only happen if you forgot to put `plt.ion()` earlier on.